# How can I change the product display order in the front end?

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I change the product display order in the front end (grid or list) by setting some preferences from back-end? I guess it should be other than best value and name from the default Magento display order property.

[image]

Comment: In the categories you can select a number of different attributes did you see that?

Comment: @Klettseb I have added screenshot. Is this what you expected?

Comment: No I mean when you go into a category page there you can select different sort options

Comment: @Klettseb You mean i.e Best Value, Price, Top Seller